# Which fixed-wing aircraft has the highest number of required flight crew members?

Tags: aviation-history

Most modern airliners require two pilots to operate. Older airliners require a flight crew of three: two pilots plus one flight engineer.

Has there ever been an aircraft where the number of required flight crew members is extraordinarily high, for example five or six?

To clarify the question:

- "required flight crew member" is the number required by relevant regulations, not the number needed to physically operate the plane. If that number is not met, the plane could not legally have taken off
- gunners / weapon operators of military aircraft who are not necessary for a safe flight are not included
- flight attendants are not included

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which airplanes require two (or more) pilot/operators?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/20862/which-airplanes-require-two-or-more-pilot-operators)

Comment: @RoboKaren: Not really a duplicate.

Comment: More of a related as the linked question is for contemporary airliners.

Comment: Do you mean *flight* crew members? Flight attendants are required crew members for many large aircraft operations, and the required number of flight attendants can easily be 5+ in addition to flight crew.

Comment: @JonathanWalters flight attendants are only required if passengers are onboard (-:

Comment: Yes, by relevant regulations flight attendants are required crewmembers in order to takeoff legally when passengers are aboard. Certain operations also legally require additional flight crewmembers when passengers are aboard, or when a certain number of passengers are aboard. The distinction between required flight and non-flight crewmembers is relevant.

Comment: @JonathanWalters The number of required FAs could actually be even 10 or more, depending on the size of aircraft and seating arrangement. The general rule is 1 FA per 50 pax. IIRC, there are some A380 configs flying with 500+ seats.

Comment: @reirab Exactly! And for the FAA it's generally per 50 pax seats, occupied or not.

Comment: I can't find a good source, but I believe the Kazakh I'll-76 in the Chakri Dadri mid-air collision had a 5-member flight crew. I believe it was 2 pilots, flight eng., navigator and radio operator.

Comment: This question makes me wonder what the minimum required crew for Airforce One is.

Comment: @Mast: hey, I have an idea - why not take the plane up with Trump onboard, then have the crew bail out one-by-one until the plane can't fly anymore! Anything for science..!!!!

Comment: @Mast -- it's four: two pilots, a F/E, and a nav (at least for a functional check flight) -- doubt it's changed since [the 90s](http://code7700.com/1991_test_pilot.htm)

Comment: It's only sort of fixed-wing, but the [Mil V-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_V-12) had a crew of 6: pilot, co-pilot, flight engineer, electrical engineer, navigator, and radio operator.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In addition to the An-225, a few historic examples at five, a couple at six, and one (possibly) at seven.

I don't know how firmly worded regulations were at the time so I can't speak as to whether all of them were absolutely required to be in place for takeoff. As neither of the six-crew airliners entered service, the question might be moot for them anyway.

Two prototype airliners with six -

- The [Bristol Brabazon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol_Brabazon) had a [crew of six](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1949/1949%20-%201662.html) - two pilots, navigator, radio operator, two flight engineers.
- The [Saunders-Roe Princess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saunders-Roe_Princess) also had six; again, two pilots, two flight engineers, radio operator and navigator. (I can't find a clear statement, but see [this cockpit diagram](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1952/1952%20-%202843.html))

At least one operational airliner had a minimum of five -

- The [Boeing 314](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_314_Clipper) had a [flight crew of five](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1939/1939%20-%201065.html) - two pilots, a navigator, a radio operator, and a mechanic. However, for the intended long-duration flights, it [apparently carried](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1939/1939%20-%201067.html) two full crews *plus* two additional people - a chief engineer and a clerk. Relief crew are probably outside the scope of your question, but it's not clear to me if the two additional crew would have been "required" even for a shorter flight (the engineer maybe, the clerk probably not) - so the answer might be six.

And some military aircraft with five or more -

- The [Zeppelin-Staaken R.VI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeppelin-Staaken_R.VI) *apparently* had a flight crew of seven (commander, pilot, copilot, radio operator, fuel engineer, and two engine mechanics) - I say apparently because that list doesn't seem to mention gunners. There may have been some duplication of roles.
- The [Linke-Hofmann R.I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linke-Hofmann_R.I) (did not enter service) appears to have had a flight crew of six, but the details are sketchy.
- I *think* the basic "flying" crew of [the B-36](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_B-36_Peacemaker) was five, after taking out everyone with a combat duty - two pilots, one engineers, radio operator & navigator; see [this list](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eflKhY26inwC&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false) - but it's hard to break out the exact roles and determine who was there for relief purposes. The [XC-99 cargo variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convair_XC-99) also had a crew of five, which seems consistent with this.
- The [Me 323 transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_323) had a crew of five not counting gunners (two pilots, two flight engineers, radio operator)

Comment: The British "V" bombers had crews of five.  Two pilots, an air electronics officer, navigation RADAR officer (doubled up as refueller on the Victor and later on  the Vulcan) and navigation plotter.  There were two additional stations for relief pilots and crew chiefs and long range "ranger" flights.  I believe that the B52 crew is similarly made up.

Comment: Five was very common for long-distance aircraft: pilot, co-pilot, engineer/mechanic, radio operator, and navigator.

Comment: @Simon I think the Vulcan bomber carried 5 officiers on the flight deck, but there was only two ejector seats for the pilots. If the other 3 had to bail out of the plane, well the procedure was awful and you would either die sitting in the plane when it crashed, or die hitting the plane when you jumped out of it.

Comment: "two pilots, one engineers, radio operator & navigator" on the B-36 adds up to four, not five. Did you mean **two** engineers?

Comment: @DanHulme: Two pilots. One engineer. One radio operator. One navigator. Compare e.g. Saunders-Roe Princess.

Comment: Oh, "radio operator & navigator" isn't one position. This is why we need the Oxford comma! :-)

Comment: @mickburkejnr - well, *that* could lead to some awkward conversations. "Well, lads, it looks like we're going down. Now, as there's only two ejector seats for the pilots, I'm afraid you lot will have to stay in the aircraft, or use the ridiculously dangerous and very likely fatal manual bail-out procedure. Now, who's for the 'stay in the plane without a pilot' option and who's for the 'probably fatal procedure'? Come on, now, don't just sit there sitting on your hands with murderous looks in your eyes and...oh. Oh, dear. Now, let's not do anything hasty here, lads, nothing unfortunate..." :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis Fortunately for the pilots, they could bail out of that conversation pretty easily...

Comment: _A clerk?!_ To do the flight data recording, I suppose:)

Comment: @BobJarvis in the documentaries I've seen about the Vulcan, that was basically the conversation. Everyone on the plane knew the score if the plane was shot down. Luckily I don't think they lost any crew on the Vulcan, as I think one was destroyed but didn't contain any crew.

Comment: @Pavel it seems the "flight clerk" had the duties of a ship's purser - responsible for paperwork, some cargo (eg mail), and generally dealing with passengers; this presumably explains why the term "purser" is now used for the senior steward. [This article](https://www.flightglobal.com/pdfarchive/view/1938/1938%20-%202510.html) from 1938 gives an idea of the role - and, interestingly, clearly differentiates them from the "steward".

Comment: @Pavel thinking about it, this would probably make a good question in its own right :-)

Answer (score 33):

The [Antonov An-225 Mriya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225_Mriya) requires a crew of six- you have the pilot, copilot, 2 flight engineers, navigator and a communications specialist/radio operator.

[image: An-225 Cockpit]

An-225 cockpit; image from [sas1946.com](https://www.sas1946.com/main/index.php?topic=43114.0)

Comment: Seems like [some older](http://www.airvectors.net/avantgt.html) An-124 also require six crew.

Comment: The smiley-face upholstery is...disturbing...and is that red book a Bible? (Let us read from the Book of Aircraft, chapter 12, verses 7 through 22: And then St. Orville spake, saying: "Oh, Lord, bless this, thy AN-225, and keep it flying, in thy mercy". And the Lord did bless it. And then St. Orville said: "First shalt thou lower the flaps. Then shalt thou advance the throttles to 3. Three shall be the number thou shalt advance the throttles to, and the number thou shalt advance the throttles to is 3. Thou shalt not advance them to 4, nor to 2, unless thou proceedeth to 3. FIVE IS RIGHT OUT!")

Comment: @BobJarvis zoom in on the image, I don't think they're faces. Not sure what they are though.  They look vaguely shell like, but only if a bit abstracted.  The bottom part has a vague resemblance to a B2 with the ragged back wing edge, in that case I'm not sure what the top bits are unless they're supposed to be a cloud of flairs.  OTOH a Soviet/Russian design is unlikely to use an image of a USAF aircraft in its styling.  An heavily abstracted bird perhaps?

Comment: You're right - they're not smiley faces. They appear to be...aliens from Space Invaders! (/*face-smack*/) How could I **possibly** have gotten that wrong?!?!? :-)

Answer (score 6):

While only one was built, plus two copies which were built in Italy, the Dornier DO-X with twelve engines, is listed as having a flight crew of 10 to 14 during normal operation. Twelve of the relatively high maintenance engines of that era must have been a handful to keep operational during flights.

[Dornier DO-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dornier_Do_X)

Comment: While the Do-X certainly needed a big crew, I'm afraid the number of 14 includes stewards as well.

Answer (score -3):

HP-1500 had 9 crew max but could have 8

Comment: Do you have any source for that?

Comment: Based on the armament listed in the Wikipedia article, it seems likely that the "eight or nine" includes three gunners and a bombardier.